# Reset size of a control to its default

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, size, controls

How do I reset he size of a control to its default in Windows Forms?

I tried setting the size to (-1,-1), but that didn't work, though Height was getting set to default.

Comment: @ArsenMkrt the size it has when you first create it.

Comment: did you try to save it on load, and to assign back when you want to reset?

Comment: No didn't save it on load. I have several of those controls, want to make use of default size to reset their size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the `DefaultSize` property of a control.

```
Size GetDefaultSize(Control ctrl)
{
    PropertyInfo pi = ctrl.GetType().GetProperty("DefaultSize", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    return (Size)pi.GetValue(ctrl, null);
}

myCtrl.Size = GetDefaultSize(myCtrl);
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.defaultsize.aspx) :

> The DefaultSize property represents the Size of the control when it is
>   initially created.

Comment: DefaultSize is a Protected property.

Comment: @LarsTech Updated answer to use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I modified follow code and now worked.

```
public struct myControl
{
    public string name;
    public Size size;
}

List<myControl> lstControlSize = new List<myControl>();
myControl defControl = new myControl();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SaveAllControls();
}

public void SaveAllControls()
{
    foreach (Control defaultControl in this.Controls)
    {
        if (defaultControl != null)
        {
            defControl.name = defaultControl.Name;
            defControl.size = defaultControl.Size;
            this.lstControlSize.Add(defControl);
        }
    }
}

public void ResetSizeAllControls()
{
    foreach (myControl defaultControl in this.lstControlSize)
    {
        foreach (Control resizeControl in this.Controls)
        {
            if (resizeControl != null)
            {
                if (resizeControl.Name == defaultControl.name)
                {
                    resizeControl.Size = defaultControl.size;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work, as you're saving a reference to the control, you're not capturing the size. Moreover, you are doing so after the call to `InitializeComponent()`, in which the sizes are changed anyways.

Comment: **SaveAllControls()** will save all controls on form to collection, also size of control. When **ResetSizeAllControls()** called, all size of controls on form will be replace with default controls size from collection.

Comment: I have not tried it, my assumption: Changes to the size of control occurs after the form is active (after **InitializeComponent()** executed).

Comment: (1) Sizes are changed **during** `InitializeComponent()`, (2) This does not matter at all because you are only saving a reference to the control. You could save the `Size` of the control (which is a struct - therefore a value type) before `InitializeComponent()` and that could probably work.

Comment: You are right, i modified above code. Thanks for the explanation.